# Merge rows with duplicates in one column but with multiples differents values in another

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

I have a pandas dataframe with the title of the questions, numbers and the meaning of theses numbers, my goal is to create a glossary by joigning the *response_number* and *response_meaning* columns and removing duplicates for the *Question* column

I have already joined the *response_number* and *response_meaning* columns with this line of code into a new *join* column:

```
df['join'] = df[['response_number', 'response_meaning']].agg(' : '.join, axis=1)
```

Here is an example of what I'm working with and done:

```
Question    response_number    response_meaning           join

sys_RespStatus      2             Uncomplete            2 : Uncomplete            
sys_RespStatus      4             Disqualified          4 : Disqualified          
sys_RespStatus      5             Complete              5 : Complete              
Q0                  1                 YES               1 : YES
Q0                  2                 NO                2 : NO
...                ...                ...                ...
efgtb               2                  B                2 : B
efgtb               3                  C                3 : C
efgtb               4                  D                4 : D
Q1301B              1                 YES               1 : YES
Q1301B              2                 NO                2 : NO
```

And here is what I would like:

```
Question        glossary    

sys_RespStatus  2 : Uncomplete,
                4 : Disqualified,
                5 : Complete
                

Q0              1 : YES,
                2 : NO    

...               ...       
efgtb           2 : B,
                3 : C,
                4 : D  

Q1301B          1 : YES,
                2 : NO
```

Any help, advices or hints is appreciated, thx!!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to create a multiindex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','C'], 'join':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df.set_index(['Q', 'join'])
```

Output:

```
Q   join
A   1
    2
    3
B   4
    5
C   6
```

This just uses a simpler dataframe as an example, the same code (`df.set_index(['Question', 'join'])`) can easily be applied to yours.